# How to create faster Pythagorean triples?

Tags: algorithm, math

As we know, with the previous three positive integers (a < b < c), if it is three sides of the triangles are called Pythagorean Triple.

Given integers a. How to find the remaining two of the three Pythagorean quickly.

However, if there are multiple answers, the output b, c largest.

**example**:

**input**

9

**output**

40 41

(9,12,15), (9, 40, 41) are 2 answers. but is the most accurate (9, 40, 41).

I do not know how to solve optimization. Please help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: This should probably go on the math exchange, but here's a hint - reimagine the problem as finding two squares whose difference is exactly the square of the given number. That will provide you a limited set of numbers around `b` where `c` must lie. That greatly reduces the search space. Aside from that, it's probably just brute force, but on a smaller problem space. Building a table of squares and differences to other nearby entries might help, though.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us any code at all, even if it is not optimized? That is a usual requirement for this site for a good question. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ummm...you *do* know that Pythagorean triples are parameterized, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As

```
a² = c²-b²=(c-b)*(c+b)
```

you can try the factors of `a²` from smallest to largest, as `b`, `c` are largest if `b+c` is largest and thus if `c-b` is smallest. For odd `a`, one easily sees that

```
c = (a²+1)/2 
b = (a²-1)/2
```

give integers with the required property. For even `a`, the smallest workable factor where the sum of the two factors is even is `2`, resulting in

```
c = (a²+4)/4
b = (a²-4)/4
```

---

This simple formula even has an old name: [The Platonic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#The_Platonic_sequence)

Comment: You are right. The factorization is `2*(a²/2)`.